# How to construct a multi_array::index_gen at runtime

Tags: c++, c++11, boost, boost-multi-array

In the following code, the `ExtractSubArray` function is totally generic, while the `ExtractSubArrayCornerAndExtent` requires knowledge of the dimensionality at the time the code is written (to construct the sequence of RangeType arguments). Is there any way to write a generic `ExtractSubArrayCornerAndExtent` (without SFINAE to use a different function for each Dimension (which would be annoying as well as would require a fixed set of possible dimensions).

```
#include <boost/multi_array.hpp>

template <unsigned int Dimension>
boost::multi_array<double, Dimension> ExtractSubArray(const boost::multi_array<double, Dimension>& array, const typename boost::detail::multi_array::index_gen<Dimension, Dimension>& indices)
{
    using ArrayType = boost::multi_array<double, Dimension>;
    using IndexType = boost::array<double, Dimension>;

    typename ArrayType::template const_array_view<Dimension>::type view = array[indices];

    IndexType subArraySize;
    for(size_t dim = 0 ; dim < Dimension; ++dim) {
        subArraySize[dim] = indices.ranges_[dim].finish_ - indices.ranges_[dim].start_;
    }

    ArrayType subArray = view;

    return subArray;
}

template <unsigned int Dimension>
boost::multi_array<double, Dimension> ExtractSubArrayCornerAndExtent(const boost::multi_array<double, Dimension>& array, const boost::array<double, Dimension>& corner,
                              const boost::array<double, Dimension>& subarraySize)
{
    using ArrayType = boost::multi_array<double, Dimension>;
    using RangeType = typename ArrayType::index_range;

    // Here I have assumed Dimension=3 to produce the second argument. How do you construct this second argument when you don't know Dimension ahead of time.
    return ExtractSubArray<Dimension>(array, boost::indices[RangeType(corner[0],subarraySize[0])][RangeType(corner[1],subarraySize[1])][RangeType(corner[2],subarraySize[2])]);
}

int main()
{
    using ArrayType = boost::multi_array<double, 3>;
    using IndexType = boost::array<double, 3>;

    ArrayType myArray(IndexType({{3,3,3}}));

    std::vector<double> data(9);
    for(size_t i = 0; i < data.size(); ++i) {
        data[i] = i;
    }

    boost::detail::multi_array::index_gen<3,3> indices = boost::indices[ArrayType::index_range(0,1)][ArrayType::index_range(0,1)][ArrayType::index_range(0,1)];

    ArrayType subArray = ExtractSubArray<3>(myArray, indices);

    IndexType corner = {0,0,0};
    IndexType subarraySize = {1,1,1};
    ArrayType subArray2 = ExtractSubArrayCornerAndExtent<3>(myArray, corner, subarraySize);

    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Compile-time iteration generally has to be implemented with recursion. You can build the index object using a recursive template. It can look something like this:

```
#include <boost/multi_array.hpp>

template <typename T, size_t Dimension>
boost::multi_array<T, Dimension> ExtractSubArray(
   const boost::multi_array<T, Dimension>& array,
   const typename boost::detail::multi_array::index_gen<Dimension, Dimension>& indices)
{
   using ArrayType = boost::multi_array<T, Dimension>;
   using IndexType = boost::array<size_t, Dimension>;

   typename ArrayType::template const_array_view<Dimension>::type view = array[indices];

   IndexType subArraySize;
   for(size_t dim = 0 ; dim < Dimension; ++dim) {
      subArraySize[dim] = indices.ranges_[dim].finish_ - indices.ranges_[dim].start_;
   }

   ArrayType subArray = view;

   return subArray;
}

// Helper functor to build indices.
template<typename RangeArrayType, size_t Dimension>
struct IndicesBuilder {
   // Recursively invoke the functor for the next lowest dimension and
   // add the next range.
   static auto build(const RangeArrayType& range)
      -> decltype(IndicesBuilder<RangeArrayType, Dimension - 1>::build(range)[range[Dimension - 1]]) {
      return IndicesBuilder<RangeArrayType, Dimension - 1>::build(range)[range[Dimension - 1]];
   }
};

// Helper functor specialization to terminate recursion.
template<typename RangeArrayType>
struct IndicesBuilder<RangeArrayType, 1> {
   static auto build(const RangeArrayType& range)
      -> decltype(boost::indices[range[0]]) {
      return boost::indices[range[0]];
   }
};

template <typename T, size_t Dimension>
boost::multi_array<T, Dimension> ExtractSubArrayCornerAndExtent(
   const boost::multi_array<T, Dimension>& array,
   const boost::array<size_t, Dimension>& corner,
   const boost::array<size_t, Dimension>& subarraySize)
{
    using ArrayType = boost::multi_array<T, Dimension>;
    using RangeType = typename ArrayType::index_range;

    // Build a random-access container with the ranges.
    std::vector<RangeType> range;
    for (size_t i = 0; i < Dimension; ++i)
       range.push_back(RangeType(corner[i], corner[i] + subarraySize[i]));

    // Use the helper functor to build the index object.
    const auto index = IndicesBuilder<decltype(range), Dimension>::build(range);

    return ExtractSubArray<T, Dimension>(array, index);
}

int main() {
   using ArrayType = boost::multi_array<double, 3>;
   using IndexType = boost::array<size_t, 3>;

   ArrayType myArray(IndexType({{3,3,3}}));

   IndexType corner = {0,0,0};
   IndexType subarraySize = {1,1,1};
   ArrayType subArray2 = ExtractSubArrayCornerAndExtent(myArray, corner, subarraySize);

   return 0;
};
```

The addition to your code is the `IndicesBuilder` template struct that has a static function to build one dimension of the index object. That static function calls itself (with different template arguments) to build all the dimensions. Recursion is terminated by a specialization of `IndicesBuilder` that returns the first dimension. Hooray for trailing return types!

I compiled and ran this code without fatal errors, but I did not do any further testing so there may be minor bugs. The general approach should work, though.

Comment: If I understand it correctly, in the function `ExtractSubArrayCornerAndExtent`, we should use `range.push_back(RangeType(corner[i], corner[i]+subarraySize[i]));`, right?

Comment: @astroboylrx I think you're right. Thanks for the correction.